# Django REST framework issue : How to get action attribute in middleware

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, middleware

I want to check my action or some limitation in middleware, but i can't get the action in middleware, I always get None.

I tried the following code. My middleware look like the following code. And when i create a new project. I need to get the action name, because i just need to limit the create method. Not the other @action method also POST method.

```
class MyMiddleware:
    EXEMPT_URLS = ['some url']  # Add the URLs that should be exempted

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def get_record_count(self, viewset_name):
        # Define a mapping between viewset names and model classes
        model_mapping = {
            'projects': Project,
            'datas': Data,
            'decisions': Decision

        }

        # Get the model class corresponding to the viewset name
        model_class = model_mapping.get(viewset_name)
        return model_class.objects.count() if model_class else 0

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Call the next middleware in the stack
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if request.path_info.lstrip('/') in self.EXEMPT_URLS:
            return None

        # Check if the request is a POST method
        if request.method != 'POST':
            return None

        resolver_match = request.resolver_match
        print(resolver_match) # this is ResolverMatch(func=aiwinops.apps.project.views.ProjectViewSet, args=(), kwargs={}, url_name=project-list, app_names=[], namespaces=[], route=api/v1/projects$)
        print(view_func.cls) # <class 'myproject.apps.project.views.ProjectViewSet'>

        if not resolver_match:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'URL does not match any view'}, status=404)

        if hasattr(view_func, 'cls') and hasattr(view_func.cls, 'action'):
            action = view_func.cls.action
            # Now you can check if the action is 'create'
            if action == 'create':
                viewset_name = resolver_match.url_name.split('-')[0]

                # Load the license data
                with open('.license.json', 'r') as license_file:
                    license_data = json.load(license_file)

                # Check app enable status and limitations
                permission_data = license_data.get(viewset_name, {})
                if not permission_data.get('enabled', False):
                    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Viewset is not enabled'}, status=403)

                limitation_number = permission_data.get('number', 0)
                if limitation_number == -1:  # No limitation
                    return None

                db_record_count = self.get_record_count(viewset_name)
                if db_record_count < limitation_number:
                    return None
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Limitation exceeded'}, status=403)
        else:
            return None
```

and my router like this,

```
from myproject.apps.project import views as project_views

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register('projects', project_views.ProjectViewSet)
```

and my Projectviewset like this

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']
   queryset = Project.objects.all().order_by('-created_time')
```

I need get action in middleware so that I can limit some condition in some action. But i still get none or `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'action'`. Please help ~~

Comment: request.method gives you POST, GET etc. it will not give [create, get, update].